# Number of features in dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am working on loading a dataset from a pickle file like this

```
""" Load the dictionary containing the dataset """
with open("final_project_dataset.pkl", "r") as data_file:
    data_dict = pickle.load(data_file)
```

It works fine and loads the data correctly. This is an example of one row:

```
'GLISAN JR BEN F': {'salary': 274975, 'to_messages': 873, 'deferral_payments': 'NaN', 'total_payments': 1272284, 'exercised_stock_options': 384728, 'bonus': 600000, 'restricted_stock': 393818, 'shared_receipt_with_poi': 874, 'restricted_stock_deferred': 'NaN', 'total_stock_value': 778546, 'expenses': 125978, 'loan_advances': 'NaN', 'from_messages': 16, 'other': 200308, 'from_this_person_to_poi': 6, 'poi': True, 'director_fees': 'NaN', 'deferred_income': 'NaN', 'long_term_incentive': 71023, 'email_address': 'ben.glisan@enron.com', 'from_poi_to_this_person': 52}
```

Now, how can get the number of features? e.g `(salary, to_messages, .... , from_poi_to_this_person)` ?

I got this row by printing my whole dataset (`print data_dict`) and this is one of the results. I want to know how many features are there is general i.e. in the whole dataset without specifying a key in the dictionary.

Thanks

Comment: So, you want to get the number of items in the dictionary `'GLISAN JR BEN F'`?

Comment: Nope. I want to know how many features in my dictionary

Comment: @Salma What do you mean by **how many features** explain with example.

Comment: @AbdulFatir I mean, is there a way to know how many features are there in my dictionary without specifying an existing key? It is like if I have a dataset and I want to know how many columns I have without querying a specific key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```
no_of_features = len(data_dict[data_dict.keys()[0]])
```

This will work only if all your keys in `data_dict` have same number of features.

<strike>or simply</strike>

```
no_of_features = len(data_dict['GLISAN JR BEN F'])
```

Comment: Yes, exactly like the first line! Is there a way on how to do it without specifying a key? thanks

Comment: @Salma Pls mark as the answer if it works for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Apply `sum` to the `len` of each nested dictionary:

```
sum(len(v) for _, v in data_dict.items())
```

`v` represents a nested dictionary object.

Dictionaries will *naturally* return their keys when you call an iterator on them (or something of that sort), so calling `len` will return the number of keys in each nested dictionary, viz. number of features.

If the features may be duplicated across nested objects, then collect them in a set and apply `len`

```
len(set(f for v in data_dict.values() for f in v.keys()))
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I meant. I got this row by printing my whole dataset  (print data_dict) and this is one of the results. I want to know how many features are there is general i.e. in the whole dataset.

Answer (score 1):

```
""" Load the dictionary containing the dataset """
with open("final_project_dataset.pkl", "r") as data_file:
  data_dict = pickle.load(data_file)
  print len(data_dict)
```

Comment: This will print the number of keys or rows that I have not the number of features.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to find out the size of the set of all unique field names used in the row dictionaries. You can find that like this:

```
data_dict = {
    'red':{'alpha':1,'bravo':2,'golf':3,'kilo':4},
    'green':{'bravo':1,'delta':2,'echo':3},
    'blue':{'foxtrot':1,'tango':2}
}   
unique_features = set(
    feature
    for row_dict in data_dict.values()
    for feature in row_dict.keys()
)
print(unique_features)
# {'golf', 'delta', 'foxtrot', 'alpha', 'bravo', 'echo', 'tango', 'kilo'}
print(len(unique_features))
# 8
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer
https://discussions.udacity.com/t/lesson-5-number-of-features/44253/4

where we choose 1 person in this case **SKILLING JEFFREY K** within the database called **enron_data**. and then we print the lenght of the keys in the dictionary.

```
print len(enron_data["SKILLING JEFFREY K"].keys())
```