# Python3 to find number of features in pickle

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, pickle

I read this question which applies to Python 2, [Number of features in dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38050896/number-of-features-in-dictionary)

Then I followed solution to this question, but it does not work, [TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17322668/typeerror-dict-keys-object-does-not-support-indexing)

How to find number of features in each pickle object

Here is github repository (if needed), https://github.com/udacity/ud120-projects

Modified code for `/datasets_questions/explore_enron_data.py`

```
import pickle
import pprint

enron_data = pickle.load(open("../final_project/final_project_dataset.pkl", "rb"))
pp=pprint.PrettyPrinter()
pp.pprint(enron_data)
print("Number of people:",len(enron_data))

no_of_features = len(list(enron_data.keys()))  

print("Number of features:",no_of_features)
```

I expect the following output

```
Number of people: 146
Number of features: 21
```

This is what I get instead

```
Number of people: 146
Number of features: 146
```

Answer (score 0):

If you print all enron_data, you will have

```
{'METTS MARK': {'salary': 365788, 'to_messages': 807, 'deferral_payments': 'NaN', //etc
```

As you see, you have names as a key and {features} as  values. These features have also their own key and values. So, you cannot just count a length of enron_data.keys(). You better of

```
print(len(enron_data['METTS MARK']))
```

The output is

```
21
```